# Not able to see text of Bottom Label in JSQMessagesViewController

Tags: ios, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am trying to add Sent/Unsent status message to all outgoing chat bubbles. For this, I am retuurning 40 from heightForCellBottomLabelAtIndexPath method.

Also from attributedTextForCellBottomLabelAtIndexPath method I am returning a attributed string. For example,

1. `NSMutableAttributedString *hogan = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
   initWithString:@"Presenting the great... Hulk Hogan!"];`
2. `[hogan addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont

   systemFontOfSize:20.0] range:NSMakeRange(24, 8)];`
3. `[hogan addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor 
   blackColor] range:NSMakeRange(10, 10)];`

Now after this space between my cells have increased to 40 but I can't see any text that I am returning as attributed string. Also if I keep increasing the value from 40, space between the cells keep on increasing but cell label text not visible.

Please tell me where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As you said that you are using attributedTextForCellBottomLabelAtIndexPath but text is not visible. Would you please follow below lines hope it helps.

Step 1: Go to the cellForRowAtIndextPath
Step 2: cell.bottomLabel.text=@"Presenting the great... Hulk Hogan!";
After getting the status value from webservice, reload the collection view. At that time updated vale will be visible.

Please let me know in case of any concern.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you added following method in your code.

```
   override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, layout collectionViewLayout: JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout!, heightForCellBottomLabelAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
        return 30.0;
    }
```